# Lightbox not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, lightbox

Why is this not working in IE 8? In all other browsers you can click the images and they will become larger, but nog in IE 8. How can I fix this?
URL: http://keramiek.milacic.nl/tegels

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jquery.corner.js file is being served with a content type of text/html as your linking directly to github - which is not a great thing to do,  See [below error](http://gyazo.com/180ad775a155bcb0f9804f9f5385b36e.png) using the ie developer tools.

Copy the js to a file on your web server and repoint the script.

[image]

Comment: I changed it and saved it locally, but it still isn't working :(. What now?

Comment: How can you see that error in Developer Tools? I don't receive that one.

Comment: Have you got the script profiler started? Is the content type served as js?

Comment: @Kevin - your using mootools also! Do you need both libs? If you have no other option that to use both then you will need the jquery no conflict http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Haha ;), it was a quick little project, so I did it on the dirty way; installed Joomla (soo MooTools was a part of it). But the template I designed used jQuery.

Comment: @Kevin The lovely joomla waves its magic wand again! At least the content type is served correctly now!

Comment: @Kevin - your not using no conflict, you need to call this before using jquery to give the $ back to jquery!

Comment: @redsquare - How can I implement that?

Comment: @Kevin call $.noConflict(); before $(function() { see the link in the comment above

Comment: Thanks, did that (and replaced `$` with `jQuery`), but it's still impossible to click the images :() Any suggestions left?

Comment: @Kevin It works for me now in ie8. Clear your browser cache or ctrl+f5 the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help :), the `$(this).wrap('<a href="...">')` was the problem, no IE 8 support. Changed it to `$(this).wrap('<a href="..."></a>')`. But still no LightBox :S, I'll ask that in a new question.